# Are there any function in python to connect points smoothly in high dimensional space?

Tags: python, interpolation

Are there any function in python to connect points smoothly with a curve in high dimensional space?

The curve must pass those points.

Non-standard library is OK.

Comment: Have a look at [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html)

Comment: @eapetcho Thanks! I've already watched this, but this doesn't include smooth curve connection in high dimensional case.